# `SELECT` on `information_schema`.`tables` returns less rows if I `SELECT` the `CREATE_TIME`

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, table, information-schema

### Context

We have a MySQL 5.6.28 server with a lot of schemas on it. After a crash, we have some schema where a table `x` exists, and other schemas where it's an orphan table.

On a non-corrupted schema, doing a `SELECT * FROM x` returns the rows in `x`. Dropping the table works.

On a corrupted schema, doing a `SELECT * FROM x` or doing a `DROP TABLE` or doing an `ALTER TABLE` returns `Unknown table x`. Doing a `CREATE TABLE x (...) Engine=InnoDB` return `Error 1813 Tablespace for table 'my_corrupted_schema.x' exists. Please DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT`. Doing a `CREATE TABLE x (...) Engine=HEAP|MyISAM` or even creating a view `CREATE VIEW x AS SELECT 1` works. Doing an `ALTER TABLE x ENGINE=InnoDB` on the `HEAP` or `MyISAM` table fails with `Error 1050 Table './my_corrupted_schema/x' already exists`
Looking at `information_schema.INNODB_SYS_TABLES` or `information_schema.INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES` or `information_schema.INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLUMNS`  we see that the table `x` is there. Dropping the `Heap|MyISAM` table or the view works fine.

### Now comes the funny part:

We looked at the `information_schema.TABLES`. We do

```
SELECT TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, CREATE_TIME, ENGINE 
FROM information_schema.`tables` AS t 
WHERE t.table_name = 'x';
```

And we see only `x` tables in non-corrupted schemas (11 rows, matching the 11 schemas where a `SELECT * FROM x` works). Looks very like orphans table.... But then, we do:

```
SELECT TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, /*CREATE_TIME, */ENGINE 
FROM information_schema.`tables` AS t 
WHERE t.table_name = 'x';
```

And we see `x` tables in all schemas (905 rows), including corrupted ones...?!

How is that possible?! How can we fix that without having to drop and recreate every schema? It seems that `CREATE_TIME` is `NULLABLE` in `information_schema.TABLES` (which makes little sense IMO but anyway) but how can including that column in our select change the returned rows?! How can we fix these tables `x` in the corrupted schemas?

---

Edit: After testings, including any of the commented out columns in the `SELECT` below will return only non-corrupted tables, while leaving all commented out columns will return all schemas, including those where the table is corrupted... What's the common point between all these columns?

```
SELECT 
    TABLE_CATALOG, --  OK
    TABLE_SCHEMA, -- OK
    TABLE_NAME, -- OK
    TABLE_TYPE, -- OK
    ENGINE, -- OK
    VERSION, -- OK
--  ROW_FORMAT, -- BAD
--  TABLE_ROWS, -- BAD
--  AVG_ROW_LENGTH, -- BAD
--  DATA_LENGTH, -- BAD
--  MAX_DATA_LENGTH, -- BAD
--  INDEX_LENGTH, -- BAD
--  DATA_FREE, -- BAD
--  AUTO_INCREMENT, -- BAD
--  CREATE_TIME, -- BAD
--  UPDATE_TIME, -- BAD
--  CHECK_TIME, -- BAD
    TABLE_COLLATION, -- OK
--  CHECKSUM, -- BAD
    CREATE_OPTIONS, -- OK
    TABLE_COMMENT -- OK
FROM information_schema.`tables` AS t 
WHERE t.TABLE_NAME = 'x'
```

Comment: By "BAD", do you mean "null"?  Are you talking about corrupt tables of one Engine?  Or multiple Engines?  A power failure _usually_ leaves MyISAM tables in need of a `REPAIR`.

Comment: It's InnoDB tables, and lines marked with `BAD` means that if I put this line in the `SELECT` then I only got the non-corrupted tables. So if I `SELECT ...VERSION FROM information_schema...` then I got all tables, and if I `SELECT ...VERSION, ROW_FORMAT FROM information_schema...` then I only get the non-corrupted tables.

Comment: The `information_schema` is not a set of "real" tables, but information that is gathered as needed.  The "OK" things come from one place; the "BAD" things come from a corrupted place.